# Removing duplicates based on one value

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-9.4

```
    customer id name    Pay_type
    1111    aaaa    regular
    1111    aaaa    late
    1111    aaaa    regular
    1111    aaaa    regular
    2222    bbbb    regular
    2222    bbbb    regular
    2222    bbbb    regular
    3333    cccc    regular
    3333    cccc    late
    4444    dddd    regular
    4444    dddd    regular
```

I have a SQL query that gives me the above result and I want the result to remove any customer that has a late fee

the output needs to be:

```
customer id name    Pay_type
2222    bbbb    regular
2222    bbbb    regular
2222    bbbb    regular
4444    dddd    regular
4444    dddd    regular

select 
distinct a.customer_id, 
a.name, 
pay_type 
from table a 
left join table b on a.customer_id= b.id 
left join table c on c.id = b.pay_id 
where b.status = 'Done
```

Comment: Can you also include your query in your question? It looks like it's something a `distinct` operation should be able to solve.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this as an anti-join:

```
select *
from table a
where not exists (
  select null
  from table b
  where
    a.customer_id = b.customer_id and
    b.pay_type = 'late'
)
```

This has advantages over a distinct or a "not in" approach in that it will stop looking after it finds a match.  This should work efficiently for both large and small datasets.

Any solution that uses distinct would have to evaluate the entire dataset and then remove dupes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your tables look like, but you could do something like:

```
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM table_with_customer_and_pay_type
    WHERE pay_type = 'late'
    GROUP BY customer_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expression variation:

```
WITH orig_result_set AS (
    select 
    distinct a.customer_id, 
    a.name, 
    pay_type 
    from table a 
    left join table b on a.customer_id= b.id 
    left join table c on c.id = b.pay_id 
    where b.status = 'Done'
),

exclude_late_payments AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
    FROM orig_result_set
    WHERE pay_type = 'late'
),

on_time_payments AS (
    SELECT customer_id,
           name,
           pay_type
    FROM orig_result_set
    WHERE customer_id NOT IN exclude_late_payments
)

SELECT *
FROM on_time_payments
```